# Template parameters not deducible in partial specialization in gcc6, for a case that used to work in gcc5

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, language-lawyer

This code results in an error in gcc6 (but works fine in gcc 4.8, 5.2 and clang 3.6):

```
template <typename T>
struct outer
{
    template <typename U>
    struct inner
    {

    };
};


template <typename T>
struct is_inner_for
{

    template <typename Whatever>
    struct predicate
    {
        static constexpr bool value = false;
    };

    template <typename U>
    struct predicate<typename outer<T>::template inner<U>>
    {
        static constexpr bool value = true;
    };
};

static_assert(
    is_inner_for<int>::template predicate<
        outer<int>::inner<double>
    >::value,
    "Yay!"
);
```

The error is:

```
main.cpp:22:9: error: template parameters not deducible in partial specialization:
  struct predicate<typename outer<T>::template inner<U>> : std::true_type
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:22:9: note:         'U'
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Commandline is:

```
g++ -std=c++1y -c main.cpp
```

See [godbolt output here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22sourcez%22%3A%22C4UwtgDgNghqAEAeYBPCIB2MwngFQD4AoAZ2ACcBXAY2HgHtLRyiBvI%2BT%2BUSWBZNJmy4AqsS7wyVWvACWGDCBYT2HLgF8A3ES1E9PaHFwD0WHPmJSadWSQD68xeTsAzei1USDfY6lPD4AHUACyMANyVxLisZCHIQABNZaiM1TnYJCTI4ZPhqegwyEAAPOPgAI3p6KHgwmChKXABeeBd6khBtCV007nBDfj8hczFemLo4xOSjE2HcRmZEQgAuZe8jOQUlRDEo9N6s4BzqPIKi0vIKqpq6hubuKk7e3R7s4GS7GBIO8mAACl6tgcW2cbnIiHkwAIq3WCEmSRSoEQBy4C22kOhy0c2wSjHKUBAe3gmNujQANL0AEQATRgKAAhJSiABKTRAA%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22g6%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-std%3Dc%2B%2B1y%20-O3%20-Wall%20-Werror%22%7D%5D%7D).

I have filed a bug report with gcc here: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=70141

However it was marked as invalid (I believe wrongly). The `outer<T>` that is used inside `predicate` is a concrete type at that point, so it is not a non-deduced context.

**Is there anything in the standard that prevents this being valid c++ code?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this is a bug in gcc 6.0, and an incorrect warning in clang 3.9 (the warning is weird - because the warning implies that the partial specialization would not be chosen, but if it were not chosen, the static assert would trigger).

---

From [temp.class.spec.match]:

> A partial specialization matches a given actual template argument list if the template arguments of the
>   partial specialization can be deduced from the actual template argument list

Can we deduce `U` in `typename outer<T>::template inner<U>` from `outer<int>::inner<double>`?

From [temp.deduct.type]:

> If a template parameter is used only in non-deduced
>   contexts and is not explicitly specified, template argument deduction fails.
>
> The non-deduced contexts are:
>   — The *nested-name-specifier* of a type that was specified using a *qualified-id*.
>   —  [...]

But the *nested-name-specified* here is `typename outer<T>`, which does not contain the type we're trying to deduce. None of the other non-deduced contexts apply. So deduction **should** succeed here.

Consider the following equivalent situation:

```
#include <utility>

template <class >
struct outer
{
    template <class U> struct inner {};
};

template <class T>
struct bar {
    template <class U> std::false_type foo(U const&);
    template <class U> std::true_type foo(typename outer<T>::template inner<U> const&);
};


int main() {
    static_assert(decltype(bar<int>{}.foo(outer<int>::inner<double>{}))::value, "!");
}
```

Both gcc 6.0 and clang 3.9 compile this code without warning - but this is the same sort of deduction that would happen in the partial specialization in the original example.